# Keycloak - how to handle multiple work contexts

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak

I have an application where single user can work in contexts of multiple companies. We call such a connection (user<->company) a permit. Every one of this permits can have different sets of permissions/roles. We want user to login just once and then he can simply change permits within application without need to enter password again.

Till now we had only one application and kept this whole permission model in our own DB. Unfortunately now we have to support second application which should inherit those permits. I was wondering wether is possible to move that model to keycloak so we don't have to replicate it to every single db and keep it in sync manually.

I have searched keycloak documentation regarding this topic but have found no information att all, which seems quite odd, because I don't think we are the first one working with multiple context application.

So now I'm asking is it possible to configure our model in keycloak and if so, how to do it? Eventually are there different options? I guess that I can provided that model as a claim with json structure but that doesn't feel right to me. I was thinking about custom IDP which could provide such claims based on DB so there no spelling errors and less repetition but I feel there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to write your own Keycloak provider (SPI). There is a built in mechanism that allows you to expose REST endpoint on the Keycloak: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/providers/domain-extension
That REST could be called with authorized context only for example by passing Access-Token (Authorization header with Bearer value). On the provider level (through implementation of: `org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProviderFactory` and `org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProvider`) you have access to user's Keycloak session and object UserModel like in the following code:

```java
AuthenticationManager.AuthResult authResult = new AppAuthManager().authenticateBearerToken(keycloakSession, keycloakSession.getContext().getRealm());

UserModel userModel = authResult.getUser();
```

UserModel class has methods for getting and setting attributes, so some information that indicates the current permit/company ID can be stored there. You can use REST methods exposed on the Keycloak to modify the model within the 'session' (represented by Access-Token).
The Github example shows also how to use another Keycloak provider (ex. built-in JPA provider) from you custom provider's level, so using that approach you could try to connect to the database with your permits/company informations. Of course the datasource representing you database should also be registered as Keycloak datasource.